# S3 Transfer Manager sample shows error: Unauthenticated access is not supported

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am trying to run the AWS android samples from the following git repo:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples

I am receiving the following error message:

> Unauthenticated access is not supported. (Service:
>   AmazonCognitoIdentityService; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   NotAuthorizedException; Request ID:
>   75be66eb-11b6-11e4-85d9-9933082e5eb2)

I have configured the AWS services as per the steps mentioned in the git repo
url: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3_TransferManager/README.md

I have included the following jars in libs:

- aws-android-sdk-2.0.4-cognito.jar
- aws-android-sdk-2.0.4-core.jar
- aws-android-sdk-2.0.4-s3.jar

Also I have added the `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID`, `COGNITO_POOL_ID` and `BUCKET_NAME`. I was
not sure where to find the `COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH` so I left it at
`YOUR_COGNITO_UNAUTH_ROLE`.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15):

Sorry that you're having trouble with the sample. There are two things which I think might solve your problem.

First of all, did you enable unauthenticated access in your Congito identity pool? You can check by going to the Cognito console, going to `Edit Identity Pool`, and seeing if `Enable access to Unauthenticated Identities` is checked.

Secondly, you'll need to set `COGNITO_ROLE_UNAUTH`. To do this, you will first need to go to the IAM console and create a Role if you don't already have one. Then, click on the role in the IAM console and click `Summary`. The first thing under the `Summary` tab should be `Role ARN`. Replace `YOUR_COGNITO_UNAUTH_ROLE` with the value found there.

Hope that helps and I'll see if we can make the docs more clear. Sorry again for the trouble!